# How to extract the same sheet from many Excel workbooks

Tags: python, pandas, database, extract

I am trying to import the same sheet from many Excel workbooks so that they become many data frames, but am not sure how to do so in the right way. The specific sheet to import is 'Sheet1' from every workbook. I am avoiding using paths, and instead have a pop up box where I can select all of the workbooks at once. Is there a straight forward way to accomplish importing the specific sheets?

I have the following code, which allows me to select the workbooks, but can't get to the step of importing the sheets and creating data frames to work with. I imagine a for loop is needed, but can't get it:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
import pandas as pd

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
root.databases =  filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir = "C:/",title = "Select the location of your files (you may select multiple files)", filetypes = (("Excel Files","*.xlsx"),("all files","*.*")))
db_list = root.tk.splitlist(root.databases)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure pandas solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

workbook_dir = 'C:\mydir'
workbook_fnames = glob.glob(os.path.join(workbook_dir,'*.xlsx'))
sheet_name = 'mysheet'

workbooks = {fname: pd.read_excel(fname, sheet_name=sheet_name) for fname in workbook_fnames}
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: I inputted the file path for the ```workbook_dir``` step, but no data frames themselves actually populated. 1. Is there any way to avoid using a file path in the code, and instead use the pop up box option as written above?, and 2. If the data frames are not yet imported, what would be the next step to get them?

Comment: I don't totally understand the problem, but it's best to break it up into pieces. First figure out how to get a list of the file names you need. Then pass it to this function: `def get_sheets(list_of_fnames): return {fname: pd.read_excel(fname, sheet_name=sheet_name) for fname in list_of_fnames}`